# Dismount a USB Volume from Command-line

Tags: windows, command-line, vbscript

How do I unmount a volume (USB flash drive) via command-line or Visual Basic script?

Comment: AFAIK, neither DOS nor COMMAND.COM support USB flash drives. Did you mean `cmd.exe`?

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/296560/mount-unmount-usb-drives-with-vbscript  and also check this out: http://portableapps.com/node/639

Answer (score 5):

Check out the two following Windows utilities:

- [Mountvol](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772586(WS.10).aspx) - "Creates, deletes, or lists a volume mount point."
- [Devcon](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311272) - "Using DevCon, you can enable, disable, restart, update, remove, and query individual devices or groups of devices."

Comment: Despite the name, `mountvol` doesn't do the same thing as the other tools (which is to sync and unmount the filesystem); rather it only manages paths through which a mounted filesystem can be accessed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**DevEject**](http://translate.google.com/translate?u=http://www.withopf.com/tools/deveject/&langpair=de%7Cen).

Answer (score 1):

From a batch script, the easiest way is to call [USB Disk Ejector](http://quick.mixnmojo.com/usb-disk-ejector). ([Sync](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897438) might work too, but it wants a drive letter, which is not always predictable.)