# XP: Dismount a few non-NTFS drives

Tags: windows, partitioning

I've got a couple of partitions on my primary hard drive that I somehow managed to mount quite some time ago.  Both partitions are EXT4, and not readable by Windows.  (Back when I originally mounted them, they were EXT2, and I had a driver that worked for reading/writing them).  Currently they show up in my computer as E:\ and F:.  I'd be content to let them stay there, useless, forever, but I will be passing this machine on to another user shortly, and attempting to open the drives results in a "Would you like to format this disk?" dialog, which is obviously dangerous.  I want to dismount both drives so that they don't show up in my computer.

How they look:

[image: E and F in my computer]

The standard way of dismounting drives like this is through computer management, where one could normally just remove the drive letter.  However, that option is not available:

[image: Unable to dismount through computer management]

Other things I have tried:

- The "Mountvol" command helpfully suggested in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/264542/dismount-a-usb-volume-form-command-line) dissapears the drives nicely, but they reappear after a reboot.
- The "fsutil" command, which refuses to perform operations on non-NTFS partitions.
- KCotreau suggested trying diskpart, which was able to remove the drive letters, but they reappeared on the next boot.

Please note that I do not want to delete the partitions, as they are still used by Linux.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: If they are dismounted (by whatever mechanism) they will be remounted at boot.

Comment: But surely there is a way to dismount them permanently.  Generally partitions with unrecognized filesystems are not mounted automatically.

Comment: I think you should just remove the drive letter via 3rd party utility.

Comment: Would you care to suggest one?

Comment: KCotreau's answer is good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hate to answer my own question, but I managed to get the drives to dissapear.  I installed a later version of Ext2FSD (which includes EXT4 support), the Windows EXT driver that I used to mount these in the first place, and it was able to permanently unmount them.

Answer (score 2):

You will probably have to use diskpart from an elevated command prompt.

```
diskpart
list disk
select disk 0 (I think this is your disk, but it is cut off)
list volume
select volume 3 (my guess is you have partitions 2+3 to worry about, but you have to use what you see to go by)
remove letter=F
```

Then do the same for the other partition.

This will remove the letters, but I am not sure you can keep them dismounted on the next boot, but the letters should remain gone.

Comment: Oddly enough, diskpart only shows two volumes: the NTFS partition of the hard drive, and my dvd-rom.  E and F are not listed at all.

Comment: Try doing it with list partition, select partition and then remove letter. I am not sure about that one, but there is nothing lost if you try to do it that way.

Comment: Well, that removed the letters.  However, after a reboot, they came right back.

Comment: I am not an EXT4 expert, but I have to wonder if the letters are not somehow tied to the partitions. I am at the extent of my knowledge on this one. I wish I could help more.